# Extraer Información de LocalStorage con JavaScript

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy intentando hacer consultas desde el localStorage de Google Chrome con JavaScript, he logado obtener la información pero no puedo acceder correctamente a ella, ¿Cómo puedo acceder a la información de cada atributo?

Lo que hago es esto:

```
    var efekto  = localStorage.getItem('dataefekto');
    dataefekto  = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(efekto));    
    var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(efekto);
    notas       = JSON.stringify(dataefekto);
    document.write(notas);
```

Y obtengo esto:

```
{"trigger":"10876","data":{"bloque1":[{"ID":78491,"post_author":"23","post_date":"2018-11-30 14:21:00","post_date_gmt":"2018-11-30 20:21:00","post_content":"","post_title":"Inicia cumbre G-20 en Argentina","post_excerpt":"","post_status":"publish","comment_status":"open","ping_status":"open","post_password":"","post_name":"inicia-cumbre-g-20-en-argentina","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2018-11-30 14:21:00","post_modified_gmt":"2018-11-30 20:21:00","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":0,"guid":"http://www.efekto.tv/?p=78491","menu_order":0,"post_type":"post","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"0","filter":"raw","formatLink":"https://www.efekto.tv/videos/inicia-cumbre-g-20-en-argentina/","image":{"medium":"https://www.efekto.tv/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/g20-768x424.jpg","full":"http://www.efekto.tv/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/g20.jpg","title":"","description":",","post_date":"2018-11-30 14:07:25"},"videos":"0_ixz4zx3v","audios":"","tiempo":"hace 2 hr","formatTime":"30 de November 2018"}]}}}
```

Comment: A que te refieres a obtener la informacion de cada atributo???

Comment: debes hacer el [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse)

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas me refiero a que obtener por ejemplo el Id del author, el post_date, post_title y esa información guardarla en un nuevo arreglo para enviarla al html

Answer (score 2):

lo que sucede es que cuando guardas un objeto en el storage, ya sea sessionStorage o localStorage, la información se guarda como un string.

Para que funcione tienes que parsearla, y lo puedes realizar de la siguiente manera

```
let value = storage.getItem('key');
value = JSON.parse(value);
```

Y con eso obtendrías tu objeto nuevamente. más información en: [Json.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 1):

El localstorage únicamente puede guardar string, por lo que para guardar objetos JSON primero se tienen que pasar a string utilizando la función [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify).

Para poder recuperar un JSON del localstorage lo recuperas con [`localstorage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), pero esto te va a recuperar el string que está almacenado, para poder utilizarlo como JSON debes convertirlo con la función [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse).

Algo como:

```
let misDatos = JSON.parse( localstorage.getItem('mi-objeto-de-ls') );
```

Suponiendo que quieres acceder a una propiedad de tu JSON almacenado en `misDatos` tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
let titulo = misDatos.post_title;
```

Comment: ya lo tengo, pero ahora cómo puedo acceder a la información específicamente al post_title, cuál es la forma correcta de recorrer el array para obtener toda la información y mandarla al html

Comment: Ya lo incluí en la respuesta.

Comment: ya lo incluí pero me aparece "undefined"